# Setting duration of field in class

Tags: java, javafx

Excuse my poor naming of the issue, I couldn't come up with better one. I'm try to make simple game where I have PlayerModel with some stats like movementspeed

```
public class PlayerModel{
    private Integer movSpeed;
    //constructor here, omitted
    ...
    public void setmovSpeed(int ms){this.movSpeed = ms}
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to approach case when player gets buff that increase movement speed in my example and I want to set duration of the buff.

I'm not sure if it's good idea but I want to set movement via setter in my PlayerControler class when buff is activated.

```
public class PlayerController implements EventHandler<KeyEvent>{
    private PlayerModel playerModel;
    //constructor here, omitted
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
            //movement speed buff activated here
            playerModel.setmovSpeed(playerModel.getmovSpeed()*2);
            }
    ...
}
```

Then in my game loop I have this:

```
public void start(Stage theStage){
    ...
     scene.setOnKeyPressed((EventHandler) player.playerController);
     theStage.setScene(scene);
     theStage.show();
     AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
         ...
     }
     timer.start();
}
```

I don't know how I should implement movement speed duration. After duration expires, the movementspeed would restart to the original one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Run a sleep in a separate thread, then reset the move speed. For example:

```
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(5).toMillis());
                playerModel.setmovSpeed(playerModel.DEFAULT_MOVE_SPEED);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
```

EDIT

As mentioned in the comments, the multi-threading above requires synchronization and a simpler solution would be to use a `PauseTransition`. For example:

```
        PauseTransition moveSpeedReset = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
        moveSpeedReset.setOnFinished(e -> playerModel.setmovSpeed(playerModel.DEFAULT_MOVE_SPEED));
        moveSpeedReset.play();
```

This still runs asynchrounously, but without multiple threads.

Comment: You’d need to add synchronization to make this work. Just use a `PauseTransition` to avoid using multiple threads.

Comment: apologies for not replying earlier, your solution that you added after edit worked. Thank you